# How will JVM deal with the default properties in Serializable?

Tags: java

There is a class implements `Serializable` and has a property which type is `Object`. I got a bug when scan by `SonarQube`. It said that the serializable class's property must be `serializable` or `transient`. So I think maybe the default property's serialization is controlled by the `jvm` or container. Where can I find the articles describing this mechanism?

```
public class AHttpResponse implements Serializable {
    private String responseCode;
    private Object data; // SonarQube detect this line has `Major` problem
    .....
}
```

This class is a base class that hold the request's result code and result data. the response will be like these json string in the front end:

```
{
    "responseCode": "0",
    "data": {
        "userName":"xxx"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "responseCode": "0",
    "data": [
        { "userName": "xxx" },
        { "userName": "yyy" }
    ]
}
```

So, that is, the `AHttpResponse`'s `data` can be a `List` or a JavaBean.

Comment: In short, you can't serialize an object which contains data which isn't serializable (unless it's transient). Can you not make `data` a `Serializable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `AHttpResponse` will not be serialized in this scenario so the easiest way to make it work is to make your Class not implementing `Serializable`

```
public class AHttpResponse {
    private String responseCode;
    private Object data;
    .....
}
```

Comment: Hopefully the comment no longer applies ;) +1

Comment: here the client call the `setter` may pass an object which not implement `Serializable`. and my question is what will the JVM or container deal with the default property.

Comment: @blackdog I think if you want to transfer the Object to your server, you should tell them to set a `Serializable` object, or JVM will throw a `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: I edit the answer, I think your scenario is to convert a JSON response to a Java bean, your class `AHttpResponse` will never be serialized, so just remove the implementation of `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

In the above class, `data` is of type `Object` which means it may or may not be serializable (depending on its subtype, e.g. `String` is serializable whereas `List` is not). Let's see what [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) says about non-serializable property of a serializable class:

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be
>   initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the
>   class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is
>   serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored
>   from the stream.

As behaviour of that field is not apparent from declaration (i.e. it may or may not be serializable), Sonarqube shows the warning.

Comment: What should I correct it if the data maybe an `POJO` or `List<POJO>` or even `List<List<POJO>>`

Comment: Just mark it as `transient`, that's it. E.g. `private transient Object data;`

Comment: @blackdog Are you using jackson or gson to serialize the object?

Comment: Here I use the jackson

Comment: In which case, you don't need to use `implements Serializable`, get rid of it and see what Sonarqube says?

Answer (score 0):

As @Keijack pointed out, `Serializable` has nothing to do with serialization to JSON.

`Serializable` marker interface lets the JVM know that the class is serializable/deserializable into/from the byte stream using Java object serialization mechanism.

One serializes with Java serialization when doing something like this (example from the Jave Object Serialization specification):

```
    // Serialize today's date to a file.
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("tmp");
    ObjectOutput s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
    s.writeObject("Today");
    s.writeObject(new Date());
    s.flush();
```

If you don't intent to use Java serialization, just remove the `Serializable` interface.

More details about Java objects serialization can be found in the [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/serialization/index.html).